# Jmeter request on AWS is decreasing after few hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Can someone help me address the issue I'm encountering I tried to run for 3 hours my Jmeter script unfortunately I noticed decreased of the request after few hours. On Jmeter side it shows consistent request will generated but on AWS its not the case. Your response is highly appreciated. T

Expected Result:
I want to achieve 6000 Request per minute (5k `CacheMissCount` and 1k `CacheHitCount`) for the entire execution.

Jmeter configuration

[image: Jmeter Configuration]

[image: Request First Few Minutes]

[image: Request After 3 Hours]

[image: Jmeter Configuration]

[image: Jmeter Heap Size]

[image: AWS Memory Allocation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to generate 6000 requests per minute with 100 users only given response time of your system is 1 second or less. In case of higher response times the throughput will be proportionally lower.

1. Try increasing the number of threads and see if it resolves the issue. You might want to try out [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) combination, they can be connected via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) allowing JMeter to kick off extra threads if current amount is not sufficient to conduct and/or maintain the required load
2. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html).
3. Monitor resources usage on JMeter side like CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. to ensure that it's not the bottleneck. Also pay attention to JVM metrics especially to [Garbage Collection](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) as it may pause or even stop the threads.
4. Do the same for the system under test side
5. If points 3 and 4 don't help or the bottleneck is not connected with resources consider using [profiler tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) on system under test and possibly JMeter sides to identify the bottleneck in the code or logic.